# DynamoDB getItem just with the id (aws sdk)

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

Is there any way to **get** an **element** or **more elements** (with the same id) with just the **id** ?, without using alsoe the property `name` ?

```
  let params = {
  TableName: "TableName",
  Key: {
    id: { S: req.body.ProjectId },
    // name: { S: req.body.name }
  },
};

ddb.getItem(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
    res.send(err);
  } else {
    console.log("Success", data);
    res.send(data);
  }
});
```

});

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You left out some important information in your question, but I am guessing that `id` is your **partition key**, and `name` is the **sort key**.

In That case the answer is yes - you *can* get all the items with the same partition key `id`, by using a `Query` request instead of the `GetItem` request.

Please read the documentation of how to properly use `Query`. In particularly, note that a `Query` can theoretically return a very long list of items (which have the same `id` but different `name`) so it is *paged*, i.e., you may need to have to call it multiple times (in the appropriate way) to get all these items.

Comment: yes, I'm sorry I missed that information, I think the is the sort key abd tge name is the partition key, but I'm testing so I can change them

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** You can pull one item depending how the Primary Key of your table has been defined.

**Longer version:**
Here is what API documentation for getItem ([here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html)) says about the Key field:

> A map of attribute names to AttributeValue objects, representing the **primary key of the item** to retrieve.
>
> For the primary key, you must provide all of the attributes. For
> example, with a simple primary key, you only need to provide a value
> for the partition key. For a composite primary key, you must provide
> values for both the partition key and the sort key.

GetItem returns ONE record based on the primary key. Primary key uniquely identifies a record in the Dynamo table.

To get multiple records, use [BatchGetItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html) and pass multiple Primary Keys for the records you want to pull.